# Apex : Retrieve Data from Map< SObject, List<SObject>>

Tags: apex

I am using a lead map where the first id represents an Account ID and the List resembles a list of leads linked to that account such as:  `Map<id, List<Id>  > leadMap = new Map< id, List<id> >();`

My question stands as following: Knowing a Lead's Id how do I get the related Account's Id from the map. My code looks something like this, The problems is on the commented out line.

```
for (Lead l :  leads){

       Lead newLead = new Lead(id=l.id);
        if (l.Company != null)  {           
       // newLead.Account__c  = leadMap.keySet().get(l.id);
        leads_to_update.add(newLead);
       }          
      }
```

Comment: you have to create one more map that will contain LeadId to AccountId this way you can do that..

Comment: @Ratan he could loop through his `Map`, get the `List` on each iteration, then iterate through that `List` to find the required id. I'm not saying that this is the way it should be done, but it is possible without creating another `Map`

Comment: In one snippet you are calling the map `leadMap` and in the next `accMap`? If those are the same, your `accMap.keySet().get(l.id)` is keyed by account Id not the lead Id. So that id shouldn't exist in that `keySet`

Comment: Yeah sorry I edited it now. The map is called leadMap

Comment: Are you using this Map for other things? If yes, the answer below should do what you need(after you fix the syntax error on the constructor). If not, I would suggest rethinking your collection model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating a `Map<Id, List<Id>>` can you make a `Map<Id, Set<Id>>`?

If you can do that all you would need to do is:

```
//Assuming this is ok
//leadMap is a Map<Id, Set<Id>> account id to set of lead ids

for (Lead l : leads) {
    Lead newLead = new Lead(id=l.id);
    if (l.Company != null)  {        
        //newLead.Account__c  = leadMap.keySet().get(l.id);
        for (Id acctId : leadMap.keySet()) {
            if (leadMap.get(acctId).contains(l.Id)) newLead.Account__c = acctId; 
            leads_to_update.add(newLead);
        }
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I see this can be two ways:
1. Create another Map for Map

```
Map<Id, Id> leadAccounts = new Map<Id, Lead>();
    for(Id accountId: leadMap) {
        for(Lead iLead: leadMap.get(accountId)) {
            leadAccounts.put(iLead.Id, accountId);
        }
    }
```

Or 2:

```
Map<id, List<Id>  > leadMap = new Map< id, List<id> >();
Id givenId = leadId;
Lead outLead = null;
for(Id accountId: leadMap) {
    for(Lead iLead: leadMap.get(accountId)) {
        if(iLead.Id == givenId) {
          outLead = iLead;
        }
    }
}
```

Please check for syntax, thanks.

Comment: Thanks it worked. The solution was pretty much straight forward not sure how I overlooked it, I need to catch up on sleeping I guess. Cheers!